# Google cloud function - Python - unzip a file that is in a bucket to the same bucket

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, unzip, bucket

i'm trying the unzip a file that is already in a google storage bucket to the same bucket throught a google cloud function in Python (3.7). the unzip has to be done in the bucket : no download/upload.

first there is a module to list the files that are in the bucket :

```
rd_client = storage.Client()
bu_rd_bucket = rd_client.get_bucket(current_bucket)
blobs = bu_rd_bucket.list_blobs()
for blob in blobs:
```

i tried 2 ways to do it :

1- using the zipfile library:

```
if len(re.findall('xxxxx(.*).zip', str(blob.name)))>0:
      with zipfile.ZipFile('gcs://{}/{}'.format(current_bucket, blob.name), 'r') as zip_ref:
          zip_ref.extractall('gcs://' + current_bucket)***
```

with this script i get an error message : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gcs://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.zip' (i get the same result using absolute or relative file path)

2- using the shutil library:

```
if len(re.findall('xxxxx(.*).zip', str(blob.name)))>0:
     shutil.unpack_archive(blob.name, current_bucket)
```

with this script i get an error message : shutil.ReadError: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.zip is not a zip file

i've tried both scripts on my local machine and it worked perfectly.

i haven't found much relevant on google about this specific matter.

any idea about ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the unzip has to be done in the bucket : no download/upload.

Your requirement is not possible. Cloud Storage does not offer compute processing features that are required to unzip an object.

Comment: thanks John, in your opinion, would it be possible to donload the zip to a google drive location, unzip the file there and upload the result back to the bucket with a google cloud funtion ?

Comment: Take a minute and think to the underlying process: To unzip a file, you need to get the zipped data, put it in your CPU and then get the unzipped data. Google Drive or Cloud Storage will change nothing! You need to get the data locally to unzip them, and then write them back unzipped.

Comment: thanks guillaume, it confirms that we won't be able to process zip files in the google cloud. downloading zip to local drive is not an option in our pipeline. i think we'll have to desing an API we call to get the data.